# Pandas series Timestamp converted to numpy.datetime64 after applying unique()

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a `pd.Series` whose elements are `pd.Timestamp`. However, after applying `unique()` to the series, the type has been converted to `numpy.datetime64` and is represented in a different time zone. This behavior is a bit inconvenient because typically `unique()` isn't expected to change the type. Is this behavior expected?

```
In [49]: dates
Out[49]: 

     ym
0    2013-11-01
1    2013-12-01
2    2014-01-01
3    2014-02-01
4    2014-03-01

In [50]: dates.ym[0]
Out[50]: Timestamp('2013-11-01 00:00:00')

In [51]: dates.ym.unique()[0]
Out[51]: numpy.datetime64('2013-10-31T17:00:00.000000000-0700')
```

Comment: I think this is because `unique` returns a numpy array, not a Pandas structure, so it tries to use a numpy datatype.

Comment: you can of course wrap with ``Timestamp`` for the individual selection or ``DatetimeIndex/Series`` for the Index/Series

Comment: I've just spent some time with the same issue. Does this behavior make sense? Or will it be fixed?